# How to simulate data for those distributions which are not defined in MATLAB

Tags: distributions, matlab, computational-statistics

Suppose there is any distribution whose parameter values are known. So how to simulate data in this case?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Is there a specific distribution you have in mind?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated? Is your question about understanding how to simulate random numbers in general, or just how to do it in Matlab? If the former, it's rather broad; if the latter it would be better to Stack Overflow.

Comment: There are different techniques for different distributions. Some techniques can be used for many distributions. To answer the question as asked, it's a 'takes a book to answer' question. Please try to narrow the scope of the question a little.

Answer (score 1):

While your question is rather vague, a classic text on univariate random number generation is Luc Devroye's [Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation](http://luc.devroye.org/rnbookindex.html).

Comment: And a good introduction can be found in Morgan (1984), *Elements of Simulation*, Ch 4 & 5.